# Upgrade from Wp7.1 to Wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, manifest, upgrade

Using the built-in upgrade tool leads me to the following error.

"The manifest file could not be updated. You may have to modify it manually."

What to change in the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented on the MSDN : [Changes in the upgraded app manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207030%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Changesintheupgradedappmanifestfile)